# Why won't Mac recognize Seagate Barracuda 3TB HDD removed from GoFlex Home FreeAgent Case via SATA/USB

Tags: hard-drive, mac, sata

I purchased a Seagate Goflex home 3TB NAS system in 2012 that I now need to remove files from. I have forgotten the password sadly so after much research decided to remove the drive from the Goflex case to connect to my MacBook Pro via SATA to USB cable or the Insignia dual hard drive docking station. But the Mac won't see the drive on either of these. So, now I have a Seagate Barracuda 3.5" SATA drive that I still can't access because my Mac doesn't see it. I'm at a loss. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you hear the drive spin up? A USB-SATA cable might not be able to supply enough power to spin up a 3.5" HDD, so I wouldn't be surprised if it doesn't spin up there. I'm not sure if your Insignia dock has a USB bus-powered mode for when you only have laptop SSDs in it, but I imagine if you put a 3.5" HDD in it, you need to make sure the dock is getting power via its wall-wart power adapter. Do you know if your GoFlex system did any kind of proprietary full disk encryption on the disk? I've seen that problem when moving a disk from an external USB enclosure to an internal SATA connection.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response!  Yes, I do hear the drive spinning when connected via USB. Both the USB-SATA cable connector and dock are getting power through AC adapters.  I don't know if the GoFlex has proprietary full disk encryption but it's certainly possible. Not knowing enough about it, I had hoped removing the Seagate drive from the case (GoFlex system) would fix this problem. There's much inaccurate advice out there that prompted me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

did the goflex have more than one drive? if so its probably raid and I've never gotten a drive apart from its raid controller to mount. if it was a solo drive then encryption is your issue.

this article http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/214075en
says the following:

Encrypted backups can only be restored using the Instant Backup software and your password.  If the password is lost, then the backup cannot be restored.

if the NAS was just one drive and wasn't a backup but just naked files, i am not aware of how you could have encrypted the entire drive a la file vault so this would be a question for the seller. Poke around seagate's site to see if they have any low level disk utilities. i once got a WD SATA drive to read after everything else failed to mount or recover it using their HD utilities but i had to use a windows VM to do it. i would imagine you would start with putting it back in the go flex case with its controller and then try any seagate tools from there. Good luck.